# Rewriting URLs containing # and htaccess removing formatting

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to use .htaccess to change the name of some of the URLs of my website but I have encountered a few problems.

1. I don't know how to change an URL name containing # (redirection to an ID). For example, I would like to change www.website.com/gallery.php#bottom to www.website.com/gallery, however, when I type the code below, it works as if I am redirecting to gallery.php (not to the element with id="bottom").

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule "^gallery$" gallery.php#bottom [NC,L]
```

2. Another problem that I have encountered is when I try to put a '/' at the end of the url, for example if I would like to change www.website.com/gallery.php to www.website.com/gallery/, the page that gets opened is the desired one, however all formatting (from bootstrap and style.css) is lost. I have tried using to following code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule "^gallery/$" gallery.php [NC,L]
```

3. Similarly to above if I try to change www.website.com/contacts/feedback.php to www.website.com/asdf I lose the formatting. I use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule "^asd$" contacts/feedback.php [NC,L]
```

I would like to ask how I could fix those issues?

Answer (score 0):

**For your question #1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^#/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Once you've tested this, change R to R=301. Make sure to clear cache before testing.

**For question #2: remove file extension .php**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

The first 3 lines help redirect a request with .php to one without the file extension. The last 2 lines remove the file extension.